# Pandas - Error when splitting row into multiple columns

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe in the below format:

```
issue_id, products
101, ['Apple','Orange']
102, ['Apple','Banana']
103, ['Grapes']
```

I am trying to have them split into rows based on ticket_id

```
issue_id, products
101, Apple
101, Orange
102, Apple
102, Banana
103, Grapes
```

I tried to explode as below:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.set_index(['index', 'issue_id'])
                .stack()
                .str.split(',', expand=True)
                .stack()
                .unstack(-2)
                .reset_index(-1, drop=True)
                .reset_index()
                )
```

but this throws `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Issue'`

Comment: what is `print (df.columns.tolist())` after `df = df.reset_index()` ?

Comment: @jezrael, it prints out   `['index', 'issue_id', 'products'] `

Comment: Ok it is good. What is `print (df['issue_id'].tolist()[:5])` ?

Comment: @jezrael it prints `[101, 102, 103]`

Comment: It is good, what is `print (type(df.loc[0, 'products']))` ?

Comment: @jezrael ,it returns `<class 'list'>`

Comment: So use `df = df.explode('products')` insted your solution

Comment: @jezrael, is there an alternative to using explode.. I am using version `0.22 of pandas `and hence was performing this way of extracting data..

Comment: OK, added dupe, there is answers also for lower version of pandas

Comment: @jezrael thank you..